# Transpose pandas dataframe while replacing select column names

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, csv

I have a pandas dataframe as below:

[image]

Which I instead want to transpose it like so relabeling the first 2 columns **"title"** and **"heading"** while the remainder are labeled starting from 0:

|  | title | heading | 0 | 1 | 2 | 3 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| **0** | Residential Zones | Purpose | 0.021688304841518402 | 0.034876345 | 0.01611880026757717 | -0.014965585432946682 |
| **1** | Purposes of Residential Zones | RR (Residential Ranchette) | 0.00977486465126276 | -0.0021642891224473715 | -0.008860375732183456 | 0.01690787263214588 |

I tried:

```
df.T
df.rename(columns = {0:'title', 1: 'heading'}, inplace=True)
```

But while this renames the first two columns I still need the remaining column labels to start from 0 as above. There are loads of columns so a for loop would be totally inefficient. How can I do this while transposing the pandas dataframe? This originated from a csv file btw

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your current dataset does not contain the appropriate column labels. Therefore, once it has been transposed you must relabel each column, however you can simply pop the last label and insert a new label, `'Heading'`, without ever using a for loop.

```
from pandas import DataFrame
import numpy as np

data = np.array([['', 'RZ', 'POTRZ'],
                 ['0', 'Purpose', 'RR'],
                 ['1', 0.1, 0.2],
                 ['2', 0.3, 0.4]])
df = DataFrame(data=data[1:, 1:], index=data[1:, 0], columns=data[0, 1:])

# Transpose the data set
df = df.T
# Take the current index col ('RZ, POTRZ') then Shift & Replace
col_index = df.columns[:-1]
shifted_col = df.index
df.index = col_index
df.insert(0, '', shifted_col)
# Pop last label & inject new 'Heading' col. label, then rename
df.rename(columns=dict(zip(df.columns, ['Title', 'Heading'] + list(df.columns[1:-1].values))), inplace=True)
```

Comment: That's great but the length of the index isn't equal to "df.columns[:-1]" so instead I used "df.index = range(0, len(df.index))" so i could dynamically get the index length. Thank You!